# How do I know the internal DNS name of an Amazon AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a system that has N servers on the Amazon AWS cloud. They are all in the same zone. Instance A wants to talk to instance B, but it obviously doesn't go through the internet. As far as I understand, the internal IP changes every time I reboot the instance. Is there an internal, constant DNS name to all my instances, through which they can interact between themselves without worrying about restarts?

Comment: I have the same problem... only two Windows servers on EC2, and I don't know an easy way to connect to one from the other with a consistent name, instead of manually entering the assigned internal IP after every restart.  Maybe Windows networking has a feature that might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal

Comment: Note that this method, whilst effective, isn't keeping traffic exclusively on the internal EC2 backbone. By using the EIP inside EC2 you are actually routing the request out to the public-facing gateway, which then resolves the DNS request by handing it back to the internal routing tables and deriving the internal address from there. Also, you can run out of EIP allocations quite quickly if you have many servers - you can request more, but there's no guarantee that Amazon will grant them to you. Just a couple of things to be aware of.

Comment: how's the billing affected by this rerouting to the public facing gateway?

Comment: @Jonners, this method never uses the EIP.  It only uses the host name of the EIP for DNS lookup (on an internal DNS server).  So there is no traffic outside of the internal network.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that's a subtlety I hadn't fully appreciated when I wrote my comment two years ago. ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to make use of 'fixed' IP addresses or DNS names using the out-of-the-box AWS instances. Even if you assign an EIP (Elastic IP) to the instance, this only affects the public-facing IP/DNS reference, not the internal one.

We use a pair of DNS servers in our EC2 estate (it's Windows, so they're Primary/Secondary AD Domain Controllers). By having all other instances use this pair as their DNS servers, we can assign unique machine names to each instance as they spin-up, and reference any/all other instances by these names.

So for example our EC2-based Subversion server has an EIP which means it's always at the same place when we talk to it from outside EC2, but the EC2-based CruiseControl server refers to it as [ourec2domain].SVNHOST because it registers that name with the DCs at startup.

Comment: Thanks Jonners. Your solution is more appropriate for large deployments. Also, how do your servers get to the DNS servers themselves? If the IP of the DNS servers change, you're in the same problem.

Comment: The DCs have EIP assignments, and these addresses are fed to each instance as they spin-up - setting their DNS references. We recognise that this means DNS traffic is routed out to the EC2 gateway (via the EIP) and then back, but it's only for these two server identities, and not for all (which would be the case if instances used the EIPs of any other instances to talk to them). We have a proof-of-concept process which runs on the DCs and announces their internal IP addresses, but haven't yet 'baked' the listener process into our other instance snapshots to avoid the gateway loop.

Comment: It strikes me as extremely odd that nobody had solved this issue in a generic way. Thanks for the ideas in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues when I first started using the cloud. I too use a setup of 2 DNS servers and add a tag to the two servers using the command `ec2-create-tags <instance> --tag Purpose=DNS`

Using the http://cloudinitnet.codeplex.com service I created the server runs a powershell script on startup. This powershell script checks amazon for the two dns servers and add them to the network interface. Assuming you have a list of dns servers at this point you can use the code below to add the entries to the dns server. To get a list of servers just query your account with the AWSSDKnet with powershell.

```
$connection = "Local Area Connection 2"
$registered = $false;

# Clean up the DNS entries incase there are any settings already
Write-Output "Clearing DNS Entries"
$X = netsh interface ip set dns $connection static none

$index = 1;
foreach ( $server in $servers)
{
    # Set this server's 
    Write-Output "Adding server $server to DNS"
    $X = netsh interface ip add dnsserver $connection $server index=$index

    # Register the server's hostname with the dns server
    if(-not ($registered))
    {
        $computer = hostname
        $address = (netsh interface ip show address $connection | select-string "IP Address") -replace '^[^\d]+'
        $rec = [WmiClass]"\\dns01\root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord"
        $rec.CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation("dns01", "network.cloud", "$($computer).network.cloud IN A $address")
        $registered = $true;
    }
    $index++;
}
```

If your servers are not windows then you can use Ubuntu or Amazon Linux "Cloud-Init" to perform the same task.

Answer (score 0):

From the instance:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname
```